# Typescript props covert to javascript props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

**I need to use this `directionLeft` in the *javascript* file. currently in is in the *typescript* file.**
I need to know how to pass these props in the JSX file.
*Please help me to do that.*

```
  import React from "react";
    import { motion } from "framer-motion";
    import image from "../public/img/me.jpg";
    import Image from "next/image";
    
    type props = {
        directionLeft?: Boolean;
    }
    
    function Skill({directionLeft}: props) {
      return (
        <div className="group relative flex cursor-pointer">
          <motion.div
            initial={{
              x: directionLeft ? -200 : 200,
              opacity: 0,
            }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
            whileInView={{
              opacity: 1,
              x: 0,
            }}
          >
            <Image
              src={image}
              className="rounded-full border"/>
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Skill;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: You can still call it the same way from a javascript file, `<Skill directionLeft={true} />`. If you want prop type checking in the javascript file, you'll need to also declare `propTypes` like you used to do pre-typescript.

Comment: Because I need to use this code in javascript not typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can use it simply in the JSX file:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { motion } from "framer-motion";
    import image from "../public/img/me.jpg";
    import Image from "next/image";
    
    function Skill({directionLeft}) {
      return (
        <div className="group relative flex cursor-pointer">
          <motion.div
            initial={{
              x: directionLeft ? -200 : 200,
              opacity: 0,
            }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
            whileInView={{
              opacity: 1,
              x: 0,
            }}
          >
            <Image
              src={image}
              className="rounded-full border"/>
          </motion.div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Skill;
```

Comment: how can I declare the type as boolean ??

Comment: You don't need to declare that type in the JSX file. Then, why are you going to do that?